# Do we need to provide a TIN or ITIN in the W-8BEN form?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, investing, international, limited-liability-company

We are non-U.S. investors investing through an LLC into ventures. The ventures have operations in Brazil but some have Delaware holding companies.

Do we need to provide a TIN or ITIN in the W-8BEN form?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need ITIN for W8-BEN, but you might need it if you need to file a return or claim of refund. You will need it if you're claiming treaty benefits, for example. Talk to a US-licensed professional. More details - [here](http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/General-ITIN-Information).

Comment: Thank you. Brazil has no treaty so we won't claim treaty benefits. Is filing a return necessary only when we return capital to ourselves (there is no regular income)?

Comment: @user13913 that depends on what income you have and how you've elected to have your LLC taxed. By default its a pass-through entity, so you will have to file tax returns on the income earned regardless of whether there are distributions or not. I suggest you get a US-licensed CPA to guide you.